# Microsoft Sync Framework Exclusion List

Tags: synchronization, metadata, microsoft-sync-framework

I have an application that uses the Microsoft Sync Framework.  I have read that it's possible to include and exclude certain files from the synchronization process.  The application has done so with the id file with the following lines:

```
Dim filter As FileSyncScopeFilter = New FileSyncScopeFilter()
filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.id")
```

However, I have been having a lot of issues with the filesync.metadata file.  One such error is as follows:

> The metadata store replica is already in use.

With my experience I have just been having to delete the filesync.id and filesync.metadata files and rerunning the synchronization, which seems to work.  Even after researching and looking into this topic I am still wondering about the metadata file:

Am I able just to exclude the filesync.metadata file to resolve my conflicts with that specific file?

What information is specifically stored within the metadata file?

Answer (score 0):

best way is for you to locate both the .id and .metadata file to a folder location of the files you're trying to sync.